# Azure Node.js Express App scaffold.xml Missing

Tags: node.js, powershell, azure

Am following Microsoft's "Getting Started" tutorial to deploy a Node.js Express app as a Cloud Service.

After carefully installing all the tools on two machines, one Win 7 and one Win 8, I get down to the point of generating "Hello World" and the tutorial suggests running the intuitively named: *New-AzureServiceProject helloworld* in Windows PowerShell.

Here is what happens:

*PS C:\node> New-AzureServiceProject helloworld
New-AzureServiceProject : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ResourceManager\AzureResourceManager\AzureRM.Profile\Resources\Scaffolding\General\scaffold.xml'.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureServiceProject expressapp
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureServiceProject], DirectoryNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.CloudService.Development.Scaffolding.NewAzureServiceProjectCommand*

Taking a look at my system after installing Powershell and the Azure SDK as instructed, I *DO* have a directory:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ResourceManager\AzureResourceManager\AzureRM.Profile

However, that directory does **NOT** have a subdirectory "Resources" and hence it never finds the scaffold.xml file....

I tried creating the subdirectory Resources\Scaffolding\General inside of AzureRM.profile.  That changed the error to simply "could not find scaffold.xml"

I tried setting the write positions on "General" to be wide open. No change.

The above error is on the Win 8 machine. On my Win 7 machine after digging more carefully into the install and going multiple layers deep into prereqs not mentioned in the tutorial, AzureRM.Profile ends up installed in *C:\Program Files\C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules*  rather than in *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ResourceManager\AzureResourceManager* but the behavior is identical.

I have looked all over the web and have not been able to find any information on the missing scaffold.xml that might point to a solution. Is this a template that New-AzureServiceProject needs to create the app? Or is this something that is supposed to be generated by New-AzureServiceProject?

Any suggestions would be appreciated...

Thanks!

Comment: I answered the same question in here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36982157/could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path-creating-a-service

Answer (score 9):

I solved this problem by copying **folder** 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement\Azure\Services\Resources 
to 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ResourceManager\AzureResourceManager\AzureRM.Profile

Comment: Please [don't post identical answers to multiple questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227). Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question*.

Answer (score 3):

Need to copy the Resources folder from:

C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Azure\3.1.0\Compute

to

C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureRM.profile\2.3.0\Resources\Scaffolding\General

Answer (score 0):

According your error message from PowerShell, it seems that you miss installed powershell **`AzureRM.*`** modules.

Please try to run the following commands from the Windows PowerShell console running as Administrator:

```
PS C:\> Install-Module AzureRM
PS C:\> Install-AzureRM
```

Then run `New-AzureServiceProject helloworld` again.

Meanwhile, if you want to get started with the node.js application on Azure Web Apps, you can refer to [Azure Website Cmdlets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt619237.aspx).

Comment: Gary - Thanks. Today, I took my Win7-64 machine, carefully removed the Azure components and started over, following the steps in the tutorial:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-nodejs-develop-deploy-app/
When I got down to the "New-AzureServiceProject" step, it again did not find the scaffold.xml file, so I tried Install-Module AzureRM and that did not run either with the response " 'Install-Module' is not recognized as ..."
I actually have this screen captured in a Word doc...if there is somewhere I can send it.(?)

Comment: Have you installed Azure SDK for.Net 2.7?

Comment: Yes, That is, I followed the instructions in the tutorial which read:
Download and install the Azure SDK for .NET 2.7. In the install setup, select:
MicrosoftAzureAuthoringTools
MicrosoftAzureComputeEmulator
Which is what I did. Clicked on the link, selected these two items, and installed. By the way, both show up in the control panel.  Is it possible that the author of the tutorial was not using a clean, fresh Windows install to write the tutorial. Ie: Is there some additional dependency that was already installed on the author's machine that got overlooked...(?)\

Comment: Could you try to follow https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/ to reinstall Azure PowerShell?

Comment: Gary, Unfortunately my 30-day Azure trial ended yesterday. However, I had already tried the link http://azure/.../powershell-install-configure/ on 4/14 on my Windows 7 machine. It went a bit of a rabbit hole because it left the machine unable to run "Install-Module" itself... after I looked around to solution to that problem, I ended up at: https://www.powershellgallery.com/  which I worked on for awhile. Once I finished that, I had the same problem. By the way, has anyone at MSFT tried blank disk -> Install Win -> run these tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the terrible experience.  This looks like a bug in one particular version of Azure PowerShell.  To diagnose, we would need to know which version - if you used the msi installer, or WebPI, you will find thins in the 'Uninstall a Program' control panel, the entry is 'Microsoft Azure PowerShell'.

One piece of confusion in some of the comments - the hosted service cmdlets are part of the older RDFE (Service Management) commands in Azure.  The cmdlets that support these are in the 'Azure' module, and not in any of the 'AzureRM' modules.

To install the latest version, I highly encourage you to use Web Platform Installer, or the msi installer that you can retrieve from our GitHub repo.  PowerShell Gallery is a great solution as well, if you are very comfortable with PowerShell module management.

I will bring this tutorial to the attention of the documentation team.  Meanwhile, if you can identify the azure powershell version and the sdk version you are using, I can see if there is a fix for the problem.

Comment: Mark, Thanks for the "heart in the right place" concern. Unfortunately, since posting here, not only did my Azure 30-day trial expire, I took a new job and moved half way across the country. The Win 7 desktop I was using for this trial got its disk blanked and was sold to a used computer store. Furthermore, my new job ends up being a PM for a huge automotive Android project (my career has bounced back and forth between cloud/enterprise and embedded a bunch of times) so I don't think I am going to have a chance to get back to this any time soon. Thanks and good luck!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Reinstalled Azure PowerShell from Web PI with the latest version from June 1st - and nothing changes. scaffold.xml cannot be found.

Comment: I still have this problem with the latest Azure Powershell and SDK 2.9. Only way to workaround it is to copy the files from ServiceManagement to ResourceManager. Pretty basic regression error but also hints again at having better version control mechanisms to allow major changes without breaking things!

Answer (score 0):

Copy content from

C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Azure\4.3.1\Services\Resources\Scaffolding\General

To

C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureRM.profile\3.3.1\Resources\Scaffolding\General