# "Could not find a part of the path" creating a service

Tags: powershell, azure

I tried to create Azure cloud service using:

## Create the Cloud Service

```
New-AzureServiceProject -ServiceName 'service-lift-and-shift' -Verbose
```

I am using Azure SDK 2.9 and it is giving the following error:

```
ServiceName: service-lift-and-shift
New-AzureServiceProject : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft 
SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ResourceManager\AzureResourceManager\AzureRM.Profile\Resources\Scaffolding\General\scaffold.xml'.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureServiceProject
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureServiceProject], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.CloudService.Development.Scaffolding.NewAzureServiceProjectCommand
```

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem by copying **folder** 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement\Azure\Services\Resources 
to 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ResourceManager\AzureResourceManager\AzureRM.Profile

Comment: THANK YOU for your solution, @Redman.  However, I had to create a "Resources" folder under the destination directory you specified and then copied Scaffolding under that directory.  Your post was incredibly helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Since you want create a **Could Service** which only exists in ASM mode, you should logged in with command:  **Add-AzureAccount**.

I logged in with **Add-AzureRmAccount** in the first time and I got the same error as you. But when I logged in with **Add-AzureAccount** in ASM mode, it works.

So make sure you were logged in ASM mode.